# Is there a way to run a MS Access query in the background?

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, ms-access, background-process

I have form linked to several offsite SQL server tables.  When the form is closed, an event is triggered to run some update queries that copy large amounts of data from one table to another.  While this is running, I lose control of Access functions.  This can take a minute or so since my internet connection is slow.  Is there a way to trigger those update queries to run in the background rather than shutting everything in Access down till that close event completely executes?

Comment: Can you use [pass-through](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/303968/how-to-create-an-sql-pass-through-query-in-access) queries for the updates?  That method can be much faster than using the Access db engine to update linked tables.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll do some research and into whether designing a pass-through update query will speed that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is No. Access is single-threaded.

Your only option is to run a second instance of Access, and then push commands to this to carry out such background tasks.

*Edit:*

You can find a method to implement this setup while distributing frontends in my article:

[Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application in a Citrix environment](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/23959/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-in-a-Citrix-environment.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Gustav!  I think I'll go ahead and execute a command as soon as my form loads to open a second instance of Access.   This second instance will have an AutoExec macro to run my append and update queries then close that database.  That should give me my background query.  I just need to do a little research on how to trigger that second database to open.  Thanks for the idea!